# Open and parse multiple XML files from a folder

Tags: python, glob

The Python code below works for one XML. The problem comes when I try to open and parse multiple XML files, which have a similar structure and are saved in the folder (line 4 -> data = open('[0-9].xml',"rb"). I am trying regular expressions, but I am not sure if that works for naming documents too.

The name of all document is **"11111.xml, 22222.xml, 33333.xml ..."** and so on.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re

data = open ('[0-9].xml',"rb")
tree = ET.parse (data)
lst_jugador = tree.findall('data_panel/players/player')
for jugador in lst_jugador:
    print (jugador.find('name').text, jugador.get("id"))
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `glob` module.

```
import glob
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

filenames = glob.glob("[0-9].xml")  # change the pattern to match your case

for filename in filenames:

    with open(filename, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as content:

        tree = ET.parse(content)

        lst_jugador = tree.findall('data_panel/players/player')

        for jugador in lst_jugador:

            print (jugador.find('name').text, jugador.get("id"))
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks a lot! It worked. I also had to add (*) after [0-9]

Answer (score 1):

If all your the files in a directory need parsed, you could just use `os.listdir()`

```
from os import listdir
for file in listdir(<your directory>):
  #if you have to be more selective inside your directory
  #just add a conditional to skip here
  with open(file, "rb"):
    tree = ET.parse(data)
    lst_jugador = tree.findall('data_panel/players/player')
    for jugador in lst_jugador:
        print (jugador.find('name').text, jugador.get("id"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! However, it gives me 'NameError: name 'os' is not defined'. 
Any advice? Thank you!

Comment: whoops, just remove the `os` from `os.listdir`